# Can leaflet show dynamic arrows aimed at offscreen points of interest?

Tags: leaflet

Using leaflet mobile maps, you can easily get "lost" if you zoom in too far or pan in the wrong direction, so I'd like to display some kind of dynamic hint arrows(?) around the edge of the map which point to those offscreen markers.  Something like the illustration below which I stumbled on [here](http://nhenze.net/?tag=off-screen) while trying to find a solution.

[image: a bit like this picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably be interested in [Leaflet EdgeMarker](https://github.com/ubergesundheit/Leaflet.EdgeMarker) plugin ([demo](http://ubergesundheit.github.io/Leaflet.EdgeMarker/index-1.0.html)):

> […] allows you to indicate Markers, Circles and CircleMarkers that are outside of the current view by displaying [a chosen icon (like an arrow)] at the edges of the map.

[image: demo screenshot]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!   Frustrating not knowing the right words to search for (I was trying things like "leaflet clamp offscreen markers", "leaflet directional pointers" and so on).    Do you know offhand if anyone has combined EdgeMarker and Markercluster?   Will experiment.